# Mounting a Persistent volume on to an already existing pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to mount a volume into a pod that is already up? I have a use case where I have to mount the user's folder on Api request(different folder for different users), I know it is possible by creating a new pod, but is it possible to just add or change a volume to an existing pod?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, you need the pod to be recreated.

Comment: though theoretically you could just `kubectl exec` into the pod and mount, for example, an NFS share manually if you needed it and it was possible.